# remote desktop connection over internet

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote-access

In our office, a laptop (windows 7 home premium 64 bit) has been set up to use remote desktop connection so to establish a connection over the internet with a specific client of the network, when it's been located outside the office. The configuration was set up in order the laptop's user to fill an ip of the following form: 143.26.65.74:50001 (143.26.65.74 is the external IP address, but obviously not the actual one) in remote desktop connection. I 've changed he hard drive due to fault and i would like to re-configure this remote set-up. I think that this wasn't made by port forwarding in the router, nor with the use VPN. Could someone please tell thow this can be done again?

\Michalis

Answer (score 0):

Except for VPN and port forwarding it's not possible to get RDP access to a host behind a NAT router. The nature of NAT doesn't allow for it, since the host inside the network first has to set up a connection to the outside world before packets can flow back to the host. Port forwarding changes this by explicitly allowing packets sent to a specific port to be forwarded to another host in the network.

That said, there are alternative protocols which allow traversal of NAT routers by connecting to a central server and let the connection go through that server, for example [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)

Comment: Should the fact that the ip used to connect with RDP is the external one, say something to me about the configuration which had been made before laptop's formating? Also, what about ":50001", what's that

Comment: Probably a port forward has been used previously then. Probably the machine had a fixed IP before the reinstall, which is now gone because it uses DHCP. The port forward configuration is probably still in the router. Check if it is there, which IP it forwards to and set your machine's IP to that.